# How to abbreviate $a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_n$?

Tags: notation, definition

We write $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j =a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n$ or $\prod_{j=0}^n a_j=a_0\cdot a_1 \cdots a_n$.

How to abbreviate $a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_n$?

Maybe ${\Large =}| _{j=0}^n a_j$? Or $\{\forall j,k| a_j=a_k\}$...

Comment: Not an abbreviation, but: $$\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\},\qquad a_k=a_0.$$

Comment: IMHO $a_0=a_1=\ldots =a_n$ is pretty short already. Don't see how you could abbriviate it anymore than that.

Comment: I really like your first suggested notation, that will also work with equality replaced by many other relation or operator symbols, it is simple and intuitive and preferable to set based hickery pokery IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think leaving it as $a_0 = a_1 = \dots = a_n$ is the clearest and you don't need to abbreviate it.

You can write it like $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^n = \{a_0\}$ or $\forall i\, 0 \leq i \leq n\; a_i = a_0$ but I don't think it gets any better.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use words and be crystal clear:

> All the $a_i$ are equal.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that $a_0=a_1=\cdots =a_n$ is optimal, but if you want an alternative, consider $$\max_{i,j\in [1,n]}(a_i-a_j) = 0$$

Comment: In similar vein one can say that the set of values has zero variance; which could potentially be abbreviated to $\sigma^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As there is already:

- $\displaystyle\sum_i x_i$, $\displaystyle\prod_i x_i$, $\displaystyle\coprod_i x_i$, $\dots$
- $\displaystyle\bigcup_i X_i$, $\displaystyle\bigcap_i X_i$, $\dots$

And one can also define things like:

- $\underset{i}{+}\; x_i$, $\underset{i}{-}\; x_i$, $\underset{i}{\times}\; x_i$, $\dots$

for pretty much *any* operator, I suggest doing the same for comparation operators:

- $\underset{i}{\Large =} x_i$, $\underset{i} > x_i$, $\underset{i} < x_i$, $\dots$
- $\underset{i} \neq x_i$, $\underset{i} \ge x_i$, $\underset{i} \le x_i$, $\dots$
- $\underset{i} \approx x_i$, $\underset{i} \equiv x_i$, $\underset{i} \cong x_i$, $\dots$

Therefore, are valid solutions the following:

- $\overset{i = n}{\underset{i = 0}{\Large =}} a_i$
- $a_0 \overset{i = n}{\underset{i = 1}{\Large =}} a_i$